# setting max values within intrinsic content size (swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UILabel that I want to dynamically resize to a degree, however I still want the mask of the label to be intrinsically sized. I was wondering if I could have it so that the label could be intrinsically sized yet have constraints on it still such as the maximum width = 200 or maximum height = 100 something like that. Also I there would need to be textwrapping within the method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Since you want your text to wrap, set `Lines = 0`

[image: Set Lines = 0]

2. Set up the `width` constraint like you normally would
3. Select the label, go to the Size Inspector (<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>) and change the width constraint from `=` to `<=`

[image: Edit the width constraint]

Result:

[image: result]

Repeat for height.

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically?